# How do I search an existing file at maximum depth using recursion?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to solve an exercise where I am supposed to search all the existing files present at different depths in a dirpath, and return a dictionary with the filenames as keys and their maximum depth as values.

I have a rough idea of how it should be done, but the function I wrote gives the wrong output.

Take a look at the following directory:

```
t4/.empty
t4/u1
t4/u1/.empty
t4/u1/looney-tunes.txt
t4/u1/v3
t4/u1/v3/.empty
t4/u1/v3/w4
t4/u1/v3/w4/.empty
t4/u1/v3/w4/x3
t4/u1/v3/w4/x3/.empty
t4/u1/v3/w4/x3/minnie.txt
t4/u2
t4/u2/.empty
t4/u2/minnie.txt
t4/u2/v3
t4/u2/v3/.empty
t4/u2/v3/looney-tunes.txt
t4/u3
t4/u3/.empty
t4/u3/v1
t4/u3/v1/.empty
t4/u3/v1/minnie.txt
t4/u3/v4
t4/u3/v4/.empty
t4/u3/v4/w1
t4/u3/v4/w1/.empty
t4/u3/v4/w1/looney-tunes.txt
```

- The empty files are to be ignored
- there are only two files that should be taken into account namely: 'looney-tunes.txt' and 'minnie.txt'.
- depth starts from 0 at the path given

the function should return the following output:

```
{'looney-tunes.txt': 3, 'minnie.txt': 4}
```

but I get this output instead which is wrong because it's not taking into account that 'minnie.txt' is also also present at depth 4:

```
 {'looney-tunes.txt': 3, 'minnie.txt': 2}
```

Here is my code:

```
def searchfiles(dir1,depth=0):
    files = {}
    for fname in os.listdir(dir1): 
        path = "{}/{}".format(dir1,fname)
        if os.path.isfile(path) and not fname.startswith('.'): 
            if fname not in files:
                files[fname] = depth 
        else:
            if os.path.isdir(path):
                files.update(searchfiles(path,depth+1))
    return files
```

Answer (score -1):

move files to a global variable out of this recur call

add else to this

```
if fname not in files:
    files[fname] = depth 
else:
    files[fname] = max(depth ,files[fname])
```

You can use os.walk instead of your own implementation of recursive

Comment: Same wrong output. I wish i could use os.walk, but the teacher forbade it :/

Comment: @alex108 just saw the files.update is the problem. A shallow location may override a deep location by update(). Otherwise you have to write your own update handler

Comment: define files={} before the func definition. While you don't have to, write "global files" at 1st line within the func deinition. Altenatively, the recur function's parameter list should include files=None then you are using the same files across the many recur calls.